# C++ Turn Off a PC within a specified timeframe given by a variable

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, system

I tried to use this code variations with different datatypes to shut down my computer with C++ in a time told by a variable. It doesn't work.

```
system("shutdown -s -t %Charseconds");

system("shutdown -s -t %Intseconds");

system("shutdown -s -t %Stringseconds");


system("shutdown -t %Charseconds");

system("shutdown -t %Intseconds");

system("shutdown -t %Stringseconds");
```

Minimal reproducible:

```
TurnOff(int seconds) 
{
    seconds = 10;
    string str = to_string(seconds);
    system("shutdown - s - t " + str);
}
```

> Error: no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char>>" to "const char *"

Answer (score 7):

`system()` doesn't know how to format parameters like that.  It takes in a C-style `char*` string and passes it as-is to `cmd.exe` (as the parameter to the `/C` switch).  So, it is your responsibility to format the string with variable input *before* you pass it to `system()`.

You can pass a `std::string` to `system()` using its `c_str()` method, eg:

```
void TurnOff(int seconds)
{
    std::string str = "shutdown -s -t " + std::to_string(seconds);
    system(str.c_str());
}
```

That being said, consider using the [Task Scheduler API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to invoke a shutdown, instead of using `system()`.

Comment: @PageUp then you are not using it correctly, but you didn't provide a [mcve] demonstrating exactly what is not working for you.

Comment: @PageUp all anyone can base answers on is what you show. If what you show is obviously wrong, you'll get obvious answers or a fishing expedition to find out what you really got wrong.

Comment: @PageUp you need to create  a [MRE] and post it in your question

Comment: Submitted the edit

Comment: @PageUp I had already covered the solution to that error in my answer's examples. You need to use `std::string::c_str()`. I've updated my answer to show this in context of your edit

Answer (score 2):

The result of `shutdown - s - t " + str` is a `std::string`. `system` expects a constant C string (`const char *`). You have to convert it, e.g. with:

```
system(("shutdown - s - t " + str).c_str());
```